# location of lib folder in linux for running the jar

Tags: java, linux, jar, executable-jar

I am running the jar file on linux then its not taking the path correct to the jar files used in the project .

Using windows i put the jar files in the lib folder parallel to the jar folder but for linux i dont know where to put the jar files instead the lib folder.

Comment: Make sure that the drive/partition where your jar file is located is mounted when using linux.

Comment: Dear Digvijay I have placed the jar and lib folder in the root directory and lib folder contains all dependent jars

Comment: `for f in lib/*.jar; do CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$f" done; java -cp $CLASSPATH -jar youJar.jar` should work

Comment: can you explain the command please , actually my all dependent jar are in lib folder in root directory and executable jar is parallel to lib folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check the **classpath:** in your .jar *META-INF* file, Place the .jar files in the appropriate directory
- use the commandline parameter `-classpath /your/local/folder/lib/file.jar`